# cytoscape.js - why do I not see a sample graph in my Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to frontend development and cytoscape.js and I wanted to create a simple example to get a feeling for how to use the cytoscape.js library. I want to create a simple graph example and used the tutorial at http://blog.js.cytoscape.org/2016/05/24/getting-started/ .

Could someone tell me why I do not see a graph yet in my Chrome browser? I created an area for the graph and a graph instance. Below is the code that is not working. Thank you much for any help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tutorial 1: Getting Started</title>
    <script> src='cytoscape.js'></script>
</head>

<style>
    #cy {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="cy"></div>
    <script>  // <!–– Below is where graph is created ––>
        var cy = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById('cy'),  //container to render in
        elements: [
          { data: { id: 'a' } },
          { data: { id: 'b' } },
          { data: { id: 'ab', source: 'a', target: 'b' } 
        }],
        style: [
        {
          selector: 'node',
          style: {
            shape: 'hexagon',
            'background-color': 'red'
            label: 'data(id)'
           }
        }]
    });  
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line:

```
<script> src='cytoscape.js'></script>
```

should be changed to:

```
<script src='cytoscape.js'></script>
```

Comment: <script> src='cytoscape.js'></script>